# How to persist AngularJS models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I am writing a web application in AngularJS with the server code written in Java. The client code talks to server via HTTP API. The web application is mainly to show statistics and basically contain graphs.

The web page contains fields like from-date, to-date and the name of the country for which the statistics are to be shown. So after selecting a few graphs ( say I have a dashboard of 5 - 10 graphs ), the web page provides an option to save the web page's state, so that, I can open the page with the same graphs still being shown. i.e., I need not have to select the name, date, etc. again to have the dashboard of graphs.

I can easily contain the from date, to date and name in Angular models. But to save the page and reopen again, I need to persist the model data into some storage media and upon reopen, I need to read from the storage media and populate the Angular model, right?

How can I do this? Should I go with some frameworks, like django, etc. where I have a separate database server such as sqlite running? But I don't want such a complicated work. I need to have the simple client side coding ( HTML + JS ) and keep it neat.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: At a minimum, your java server could provide the persistence, right? Even if it is just in-memory as a proof of concept. But ultimately you will need some kind of database, and then you could access it from your java service. Use angular services to call your java api to get the persisted data.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a client side framework.  In order to persist or retrieve data you'll have to use a server-side data base.  Talk to it via a RESTful interface using $resource or $http.